# Mysql 5.7 search values inside a json column

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

How can I search the value "ABCD" inside two JSON array in a single column? This is multiple JSON data within square bracket
Sample JSON data added below :

```
[{"id": "ABCD", "TEST1": "2002", "value": "test value1", "comment": ""}, {"id": "ABCD", "TEST2": "2003", "value": "test value2", "comment": ""}]
```

Comment: Does the posted answer work ? Please give feedback. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Json_Search()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) function. In this function, we can set the second argument to `one` or `all`. We will use it as `all` to search for all the keys containing the given value.

```
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(json_column_name, 'all', 'ABCD');
```

---

**DEMO - Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
SET @json_column_name = '[{"id": "ABCD", "TEST1": "2002", "value": "test value1", "comment": ""}, {"id": "ABCD", "TEST2": "2003", "value": "test value2", "comment": ""}]';

SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@json_column_name, 'all', 'ABCD') AS result;
```

**RESULT**

```
| result                 |
| ---------------------- |
| ["$[0].id", "$[1].id"] |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uvzrzJwd7y1mx2MhruN54A/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the mysql documentation

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_SEARCH(@j, 'all', 'abc');
```

Here you can search whatever you want.

[Document:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)